# Is there an API to tell who cancelled their inapp purchase?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I would like to access an apple API to tell who canceled their inapp purchase. Is there such an API that exists? Does Apple provide any information about the actual users who bought a subscription from an IOS app? I would like to know if their payment status on my end matches that on apple's end. What's the best way to handle Apple's Inapp purchases from payment to cancellation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use Apple's server-to-server notifications to get alerted of updates to a subscribers status, including cancellations. However, there is no direct API on Apples end to query the current subscription status of a user.

A typical approach is to save the purchase receipt from a user in your database, then periodically poll it with the apple `/verifyReceipt` endpoint to keep the subscription status up-to-date in your system. Here is a link to some slides that cover what you'd need to set that up: [How to Build a Great iOS In-app Purchase Subscription Server](https://www.revenuecat.com/2019/07/16/altconf-subscriptions-are-hard)

Alternatively, you could look into a hosted solution like [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/) that offerers a complete subscription  server (with APIs and webhooks) out-of-the-box. (Disclaimer, I work there)